# I don't understand how to fix the syntax error

Tags: java, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int passed = 0;
int failed = 0;
int N;
int grades;
{       
    while ( passed  + failed ) < N {

    if grades < 6 {
        failed = failed + 1;
    else 
        passed = passed + 1;

    system.out.println passedperc = F/30*100
    system.out.println failedperc = P/30*100

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Java is not Python, you have to put boolean expression into brackets at *while*, *if* and *similar* statements.

Comment: Thank you but I am new at this can you explain in simpler words?

Comment: You wrote "if grades < 6", but it should be "if (grades < 6)" and the same goes for "while (passed + failed) < N" -> "while ((passed + failed) < N)".

Comment: It is my first try in Java so please don't be so rude @shmosel Thanks

Comment: @IrisDibra, my apologies, I couldn't resist. But I'm really not sure this is the place for such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is completely incorrect.

This is a good start, although passedper, failedperc, F and P are never even declared.  Additionally, variable conventions are not being followed correctly.

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int passed = 0;
        int failed = 0;
        int n = 0; //don't leave uninitialized and uncaptialize
        int grades = 0;  //same here

        while ((passed + failed) < n) { //parens not correct

            if (grades < 6) {//same here and missing brackets
                failed = failed + 1; //can be changed to failed += 1;
            } else
                passed = passed + 1;  //also can be changed using +=

        }
        //System print statements are wrong and variables are never declared or initialized
        System.out.println(passedPerc = f / 30 * 100);//use camelCase don't use capital variables unless they are constants
        System.out.println(failedPerc = p / 30 * 100);//same here

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. Can you help with this one also:
@Michael Queue
`public static void main(String[] args) {              
                int avg;
                int N; 
                int grades;
                int sum = 0;
               
                for(int i=0; i < N.length; i++)
                        sum = sum + grades [i];               
       
                double avg = sum / N.length;
               
                System.out.println("Average value of grades is : " + avg);
        }
} `

Comment: Local variables are not assigned a default value. A local variable must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization or assignment, in a way that can be verified by the compiler using the rules for definite assignment.  Since your variables are inside your `main method` they need to be given a starting value.  In other words, they need to be initialized, so, just set `avg`, `N` and `grades` to zero.  Also, just a little friendly advice... have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  otherwise your likely to be downvoted on your questions.

Comment: additionally, you are assigning `avg` as an int and then reassigning it as a double in your for-loop.  Lastly, your loop has to be reworked.  N is 0 so saying for int i < 0.length is not going to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some syntax faults...

I modified and annotated as comment what and why

```
...
{       // this is not nescesary
        while ( passed  + failed  < N) { // the hole condition mut be between ()
        if (grades < 6) { //same in the if condition
            failed = failed + 1;
        } //need to close the breakets
        else {
         passed = passed + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(passedperc = F/30*100);
        System.out.println(failedperc = P/30*100);  println is a method, so the parameters mus be enclosed in ()
}   // this is not nescesary
```

Comment: `system` needs to be capitalized to `System`.  passedperc, failedperc, F and P are never declared.